# How can I get the max SortOrder as an int?

Tags: c#, linq

Upon creating a new record, I want to check what the current max `SortOrder` of any existing records is, and then add 1 to the new record. This is my query:

```
role.SortOrder = await db.Roles
    .Where(b => b.Id == BranchId)
    .OrderByDescending(s => s.SortOrder)
    .Select(s => s.SortOrder)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync() + 1;
```

What I think I'm doing in my query is to sort all existing records descending on SortOrder, and then selecting the top one, which should have the highest value.

But all my records gets the `SortOrder` 1.

Where's my mistake?

Comment: As a side note, you can use `Max` instead of `OrderByDescending` and selecting first.

Comment: *But all my records gets the SortOrder 1.* umm, is all of the item already on the same context (or committed at the db)? - the database context: `db`.

Comment: I would not use LINQ for this. You are searching the whole table for the highest sort-order, then you ask the database to return this value to you. Then you execute a query(probably an insert or update) to the database with the new highest sort-order. In this time somewhere else has done the same(or deleted a record) and you have the wrong value. This is a classic race condition. Do that in the database with a stored-procedure(or trigger or computed column). The client should not determine that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in your `Where` clause. You are comparing `BranchId` to the `Id` of the `Role`. Probably, no role with the id of `BranchId` is found, and you thereby get only the integer default value 0 from your `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`, which you increment by 1.

If you fix your `Where` so it actually returns results, it will probably work:

```
var sortOrder = roles
    .Where(r => r.BranchId == BranchId)
    .Max(r => r.SortOrder) + 1;
```

Comment: Ooops... Well, that was embarassing... Of course! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
 role.SortOrder = await db.Roles
        .Where(b => b.Id == BranchId)
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.SortOrder)
        .Select(s => s.SortOrder)
        .Take(1)
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync() + 1;
```

Comment: `.Take(1).FirstOrDefaultAsync()` would have exactly the same effect as `.FirstOrDefaultAsync()`.

Comment: Not so, take returns `IQueryable<T>`, I agree that `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` might be odd here and he can use, `ToList` maybe but, that would cause him to do extra unneeded work.

Comment: Yes, but when you then call `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` on the result of `Take(1)` the result would be the same as if you'd just called `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`. Consider if the sequence was `{4, 3, 2}`. `FirstOrDefaultAsync()` returns a task that would eventually give the result `4`. while `Take(1)` returns an `IQueryable` for the sequence `{4}` on which `FirstorDefaultAsync()` again returns a task that would eventaully give the result `4`.